# SVG Files goes over the screen in tablelayout and resize the SVG-Files

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, tablelayout

I would like to create a little game where you can send your army to other bases, who can take over it. 
I use a tablelayout to show the different parts of the level.
My pictures are svg files but it seems that it doesn't adapt to the screens size:

[image: level 1]

I need 5 columns and 5 rows for my first level. The map should be a simple square and each corner should be a base (circle). The little rectangles should be the "streets" or connections between the bases, which are going to be used by the troups. 
It should look like this:

[image: what I would like to have in the end]

**My Question:**
How can I fit the columns, rows and the svg-files to the screen size? 
Because I thought that svg images can be resized without losing its quality and android studio would do it automatically, but I don't know how to resize it. 
I have also a problem in the second row: As you can see the two vertical streets are next to each other, but I would to put the second street under the base, which is in the top-right corner.

Here the xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/base" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/street_h" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/street_h" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/street_h" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/base" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/street_v" />

                <!-- An empty ImageView as a placeholder? -->

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:src="@drawable/street_v" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**What I have tried:** 
1. For the second row using a LinearLayout (horizontal) to put the 2 images on the left and on 
the right.
2. Adding the images without a linear layout. 
3. Playing around with `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.

But none of them worked and I couldn't find a solution in the web :(

Am I using the wrong layout for my idea or do I miss an important option for the TableLayout?

## **UPDATE**

I have finally got it to compress all the SVG-Files to fit in:
[image]

I did everything programmatically to make it easier to create new levels and I used this part of code:

```java
// parameters for every row
TableRow.LayoutParams rowParameter = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
rowParameter.height = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
rowParameter.width = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
rowParameter.weight = 1000;


// parameters for every image
TableRow.LayoutParams imageParameter = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
imageParameter.height = TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
imageParameter.width = TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
imageParameter.weight = 1000;
```

As you can see the images are too small. I would like to have them close to each other. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it! All I needed to do was just using bigger svg-images and the `Image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);` method :)